# Do pictures ever get stored in RAM?

Tags: c++, file, ram

I am a beginner C++ programmer.

I wrote a simple program that creates a char array (the size is user's choice) and reads what previous information was in it. Often you can find something that makes sense but most of it is just strange characters. I made it output into a binary file.

Why do I often find multiple copies of the alphabet?
Is it possible to find a picture inside of the RAM chunk I retrieved?
I heard about file signatures (headers), which goes before any of the data in a file, but do "trailers" go in the back after all the data?

Comment: So, just to be clear, you're reading uninitialized data from memory and trying to figure out what it might mean?

Comment: `Why do I often find multiple copies of the alphabet?` Ask whoever made your compiler (at least it´s one of the possible reasons) `Is it possible to find a picture inside of the RAM chunk I retrieved?` Yes

Comment: @deviantfan - I use the g++ compiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumning your computer runs Linux, Windows, MacOS or something like that, there will NEVER be any pictures in the memory your process uses - unless you loaded them into your process. For security reasons, the memory used by other processes is cleared before it gets given to YOUR process. This is the case for all modern OS's, and has been the case for multi-user OS's (Unix, VAX-VMS, etc) more or less since they were first invented in the late 1950's or early 1960's - because someone figured out that it's kind of unfun when "your" data is found by someone else who is just out there fishing for it.

Even a process that has ended will have it's memory cleared - how would you like it if your password was still stored in memory for someone to find when the program that reads the password ended? [Programs that hold highly sensitive data, such as encryption keys or passwords, often manually (as in using code, but not waiting until the OS clears it when the process ends) clear the memory used to store such, because of the below debug functionally allowing the memory content to be inspected at any time, and the shorter time, the less likely a leak of sensitive information]

Once memory has been allocated to your process, and freed again, it will contain whatever happens to be in that memory, as clearing it takes extra time, and most of the time, you'd want to fill it with something else anyway. So it contains whatever it happens to contain, and if you poke around it, you will potentially "find stuff". But it's all your own processes work.

Most OS's have a way to read what another process is doing as part of the debug functionality (if you run the "debugger" in your system, it will of course run as a separate process, but needs to be able to access your program when you debug it, so there needs to be ways to read the memory of that process), but that requires a little more effort than just calling `new` or `malloc` (and you either will need to have extra permissions (superuser, adminstrator, etc), or be the owner of the other process too).

Of course, if your computer is running DOS or CP/M, it has no such security features, and you get whatever happens to be in the memory (and you could also just make up a pointer to an arbitrary address and read it, as long as you stay within the memory range of the system).

Comment: But do "trailers" go after all the data? And headers before?

Comment: There is "other data" stored around memory allocations, and in a system where `new` or `malloc` doesn't clear the data, then arbitrary remains from previous allocations will exist in the memory you use (including temporary allocations made by the runtime library that could be created, for example, converting an integer to a string during `cout < x;` - similarly, if you pass a string by value, a new allocation is made for the resulting string - vectors and other container types will of course also have these sort of dynamic allocation behaviour).

Answer (score 6):

When you read uninitialized data from memory that you allocated, you'll *never* see any data from another process. You only ever see data that *your own process* has written. That is: your code plus all the libraries that you called.

This is a security feature of your kernel: It never leaks information from a process unless it's specifically asked to transfer that information.

If you didn't load a picture in memory, you'll never see one using this method.

Comment: But it is possible that the allocated memory contains data from a previous process that has already ended, right? Or does the kernel also make sure to reset that memory?

Comment: @MaartenBamelis: Also cleared. This is basic security. Note that small embedded OS'es may be an exception.